# First class generic function in swift?

Tags: swift, function, generics, first-class

Swift has first class functions that can be passed as arguments.

```
func a() {
}

func b(x: ()) {
}

// Pass a to b…
b(a)
```

Swift has generic functions.

```
func generic<T>(x: T) {
}
```

But, does Swift let me pass a *generic* function as an argument to another function?

```
let anIntService = Service<Int>()
let astringService = Service<String>()

func attach<T>(service: Service<T>, to value: T) {
  // Perform type safe attaching of `value` to `service`.
}

func doAttaching(attach: (Service<T>, to T)->Void) {
  attach(anIntService, to: 42)
  attach(aStringService, to: "Hello World!")
}

doAttaching(attach)
```

…Or does it only let me pass a specific instantiation of a generic function?

If this is possible, please illustrate the syntax for defining a function that accepts a generic function as an argument.

If this isn't supported, a workaround is to define the generic function as a method of a struct, or something, and pass an instead of that. This is not ideal though, as the consuming function doesn't get such a nice calling syntax, they need to do:

```
func doAttaching(attach: Attacher) {
  attacher.attach(anIntService, to: 42)
  attacher.attach(aStringService, to: "Hello World")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised, five years after asking this question, Swift supports something a little like this which can be useful via [`callAsFunction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiconfigurationcolortransformer/3600971-callasfunction).

Here's an example:

```
final class Service<T> {
    // Implementation here
}

final class Attacher {
    // Important state here.
    var state = Void()
    
    func callAsFunction<T>(service: Service<T>, to: T) {
        // Implementation here.
    }
}

func doAttaching(attach: Attacher) {
    attach(service: Service<Int>(), to: 42)
    attach(service: Service<String>(), to: "Hello World!")
}
```

A `Repeater` can be passed in to generic code and provide useful behaviour.

Comment: I'm going to mark my own question as the right answer, which feels pretty duchey, but it has been 5 years.

Answer (score 4):

This feature is commonly called [Higher-Kinded Types](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/09/scala-types-of-a-higher-kind/) (HKT), and is not currently supported in Swift.

It has, however, been [discussed on the swift-evolution mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.swift.evolution/11567).

Comment: Hah! Really? :-) That's funny, because I'd read about higher kinded types in the past a few times, and had absolutely no idea what they were talking about. Now I know! Super – it'd be lovely if it makes a future version. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is an example:

```
func identity<T>(param: T) -> T {
    return param
}

func callFunction<U>(function: U->U, paramater: U) -> U {
    return function(paramater)
}

let param = 123

let result = callFunction(identity, paramater: param);

print(result)
```

[(You can run it here)](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/434e9c08f9eb2544f7f9970bcbfa4c1608cbe24718b3e1bfae0febe54b35cd36)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think this does what I need. So, the called function in your example, `callFunction`, still isn't getting the generic function. It's getting a specific instance of it, determined by the type of the `parameter` that you call with – in this case `123`, so an Int. I want to pass the `identity` in your example as a _fully generic_ function to `callFunction`. The definition of `callFunction` can then invoke its `function` argument with multiple types.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry, I misunderstood the post :(

Comment: No problem! Thanks anyway :-)